# C2760 compiler error with class template

Tags: c++

VC++ 2017 reports C2760 error with this code:

```
template <typename x>
struct y
{
    static void z()
    {
        using def = typename x::d<0>;
    }
};

struct some
{
    template <int N> struct d;
};

// ... y<some> ...
```

Compiler output:

```
my.cpp(6): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token '<', expected ';'
my.cpp(8): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'y<x>' being compiled
```

The question is how write `def` definition inside of `y::z`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using def = typename x::template d<0>;
```

The compiler needs to be told that `d` is a template, otherwise `<` is interpreted as a less-than operator, not as the opening angle bracket.